# For n∈N we define the $n$-th anharmonic number $A_{n} = \sum _{k=1}^n\:\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{n}$. Find explicit form of sums ...

Tags: sequences-and-series

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we define the $n$-th anharmonic number $A_{n} =\sum_{k=1}^n\:\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k+1}}{k}$. Find explicit form of sums

$a)\sum _{k=1}^n\: A_{k}$  

*$b)\sum _{k=1}^n\: kA_{k}  $*

I received a hint to check the formula for harmonic numbers:

For every n:
$H_{n} = \sum _{k=1}^n\:\frac{1}{k} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}$ 
$H_{n}$ numbers are called harmonic numbers 
Let's find the sum  $\sum _{k=1}^n\:H_{k}$. From the formula:  
$\sum _{k=1}^n f_{k}(g_{k+1}-g_{k}) = f_{n+1}g_{n+1}-f_{1}g_{1}-\sum _{k=1}^n(f_{k+1}-f_{k})g_{k+1}$ 
for: $F_{k}=H_{k}$ and $g_{k}=k$. So
$f_{k+1}-f_{k}=\frac{1}{k+1}$ and  $g_{k+1}-g_{k}=1$ 
So:

$\sum _{k=1}^n\:H_{k}\: = H_{n+1}(n+1)-1-\sum _{k=1}^n\:1\:=(n+1)(H_{n+1}-1)$

Could someone please help me solve this task? Or at least describe to me how to make them? Unfortunately, despite my willingness, I can't even start this task... Thank you!

Comment: You do how to start the task, you just don't know you know. As a start to checking the hint at least write down at the base of your question the full definition for $H_n$.

Comment: I am sorry, I just corrected

Comment: Now correct the definition for $A_n$ based on you're knowledge about the definition for $H_n$. Also where you have written $F_k$ should be $f_k$ I think.

Comment: I have also received information that we can substitute $f_ {k} = H_ {k}$ and $g_ {k} = k ^ 2$ in the formula for summation. Sorry, but unfortunately I didn't get anything more. I rewrote the content of the assignment carefully.

Comment: $A_{n} =\sum_{k=1}^n\:\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k+1}}{k}$

Comment: There may be a typo in the task. I swear there is an "n" in the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to calculate
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{A_{k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\sum_{j=1}^{k}{\frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j}}}.$$
Note that you are summing over $1\leq k\leq n,1\leq j\leq k$, which is the same as summing over $1\leq j\leq n,j\leq k\leq n$, so you get
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}{A_{k}}&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\sum_{j=1}^{k}{\frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j}}}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}{\frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j}\sum_{k=j}^{n}{1}}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}{\frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j}(n-j+1)}\\
&=(n+1)\sum_{j=1}^{n}{\frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j}}-\sum_{j=1}^{n}{(-1)^{j+1}}\\
&=(n+1)A_{n}-\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 & \text{ if $n$ is odd}\\
0 & \text{ if $n$ is even}
\end{array}\right.\\
&=(n+1)A_{n}-\frac{1-(-1)^n}{2}
\end{align*}
And the same trick works for b).